# Wrapping a transacted Stored Procedure inside a transaction

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to get this working for a while.

I have a stored procedure (we'll call it `SPA`) written by another developer that does multiple inserts into the database and all of those inserts are wrapped inside a transaction in the stored procedure. I also have another stored procedure that doesn't use transactions (call it `SPB`).

From my .NET code, I need to wrap both of these stored procedures in a transaction as well to make sure that if `SPB` isn't successful, then all of `SPA` is rolled back. Unfortunately this isn't working for me. The error I get is:

> Cannot roll back SALE. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.

I've confirmed that `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` is always being called inside `SPA` before exiting. My .NET code is pretty simple:

```
try {
    conn.Open();
    trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    prod.Connection = conn;
    prod.Transaction = trans;

    // Execute SPA
    // Execute SPB

} catch (Exception ex) {
    trans.Rollback();
} finally {
    conn.Close();
}
```

If I take .NET out of the equation and simply use SSMS to wrap the SP like so I get the same error message.

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spSPA] [...]
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
COMMIT TRAN
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

`SPA` looks something like:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN SALE

IF SomeCondition
  DoSomething
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRAN SALE
  RETURN 100

IF SomeCondition
  DoSomething
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRAN SALE
  RETURN 200

...

COMMIT TRAN SALE
RETURN 0

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN SALE
END CATCH
```

Comment: Even if you create a new transaction in SPB, the transaction is SPA will be committed or rolled back independently.

Comment: @codemonkeh I don't want to create a transaction in SPB, I want an outer transaction to cover both SPA and SPB. According to nested transactions in SQL Server, the inner transaction commit (the one in SPA) should be ignored and my outer transaction in .NET should ultimately commit or rollback everything.

Comment: Ah you're right. The error implies that you are missing a commit statement. Perhaps you need to commit it explicitly in the try block?

Comment: Is the error occurring in the catch block?  If so, what is the exception that causes the Rollback statement to get hit?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show the structure of SPA

Comment: I assume in the real SP you have BEGIN/END around the ELSE conditions?

Comment: @PhilSandler Yes the syntax is right in the real code

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered my issue. I'm getting the warning `Cannot roll back SALE. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.` because if you have a nested transaction, on rollback you MUST specify the name of the outermost transaction. Of course I wouldn't know what the name of that transaction is.

The workaround is to use savepoints like described on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx). Therefore I have to make checks to see if there is an existing transaction and if so, use savepoints. Otherwise, create my own:

```
DECLARE @TRANCOUNT int
SET @TRANCOUNT = @@TRANCOUNT

IF @TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN TRAN
ELSE SAVE TRANSACTION SALE
```